# Redefining a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I need to redefine the jQuery val() function, but I don't want to mess with the source code. Is it possible to modify it on just one element?

Specifically, I need to do something like this:`$("div.smth").val = function() {return this.innerText;};`. However, the val function is not modified by this code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead modify the function of the prototype (jQuery calls this `fn`). This is where all functions like `$(...).something` inherit from.

```
$.fn.val = function() { ... };
```

If you want to save the original function:

```
var old = $.fn.val; // `old` won't be overwritten

$.fn.val = function() { ... };
```

Comment: How do I call the original function from within the new definition?

Comment: @ulu: That's a little more complicated since there is a `this` value that needs to be passed along. You can use `old.call(this, ...)`, which would be equivalent to the previous `$(this).val(...)`. If you want to pass all arguments, you can use `old.apply(this, arguments)`.

Comment: How does this meet the requirement from the question to "modify it on just one element"?

Comment: @nnnnnn: You're completely correct, I missed that. In that case, you can check whether the element is the wanted element and if so, do something else. In all other cases, route the call through like `return old.apply(this, arguments)`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want, you need to attach your new `val` method to jQuery's plugin stack:

```
$.fn.val = function(value) {
    return this[0].innerText;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but @pimvdb was first.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers indicate how to replace the `.val()` method, but if you know you only need this for one specific element can't you just do this:

```
$("div.smth")[0].innerText
```

But in any case isn't that pretty much what the existing jQuery [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method does?

Comment: The point is that I want to use an existing jQuery plugin (autocomplete) with a contenteditable div. So I need to redefine val that is called from that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsval: function(fn) {
  var that = this;
  var newfn = function(event) { fn.apply(that, arguments); };
  this.click(newfn);
  return newfn;
}
```

Instead now you can call your normal `val` and on that specific div, call `jsval`

Comment: The point is that I want to use an existing jQuery plugin (autocomplete) with a contenteditable div. So I need to redefine val that is called from that plugin.