# How to listen to event from jQuery plugin which uses val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [cropin](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) jQuery plugin in my project and going to pull updates for it in future so I don't want to change it's code.

Inside the plugin it changes the `value` of `<input>` element using `val()` function but doesn't instantly trigger the `change` event which means that I cannot listen to event using code like this:

```
on("change", function(){
 //do something; 
})
```

*details can be found here: [.val() doesn't trigger .change() in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

**Question**: is there any workaround for this? How can I listen to `change` event without modifying the plugin code if plugin:

1. uses `val()` to modify the elements `value`
2. doesn't trigger `change` event following the `val()` call?

Comment: You can't, if the plugin changes the value programatically no event will be fired, and the only way to fix that is changing the plugin, adding a `trigger('change')` call.

Comment: You can patch jquery, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23635867/822711 or this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27477455/822711 but you may as well patch the plugin instead.

Comment: @Popnoodles In this case I will get an infinite loop if plugin author one day put `val()` inside the `change` event handler

Comment: What about using MutationObservers? https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver it is plain javascript, not supported in all browsers as it is new. I can't see any other solution which does not involve the use of jQuery or modifying the plugin source code. (The other option is polling with setTimeout)

Comment: @MichaelRomanov read the code, it won't loop

Comment: @Popnoodles, Now I see: before firing the event it checks if the value was actually changed or not. Looks good for me, thanks a lot. Will use this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decorate the jquery val function.

edit: I couldn't resist making the suggested changes as it's such a good solution.

```js
// jQuery plugin to decorate .val
(function( $ ){
  var __val = $.fn.val,
      // save the previous values to a hash table
      values = {};
  $.fn.val = function( newVal ){
    // create a unique key based on tag offset id & class
    var hashId = this.prop('nodeName').toLowerCase() + '[' + this.index() + ']' + '#' + this.attr('id') + '.' + this.attr('class').replace(' ', '.');
    console.log('hashId', hashId);
    if( newVal && ( !values[ hashId ] || ( values[ hashId ] !== newVal ) )) {
      values[ hashId ] = newVal; 
      var ret = __val.apply(this, arguments);
      this.trigger('change');
      return ret;
    }
    console.log('no change');
    return __val.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})( jQuery );

var $input = $('#input'),
    $changer = $('#changer');

$input.on('change', function(e){
  console.log('changed: ' + this.value );
});

$changer.click(function(){
  $input.val('something');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<input id='input' class="some-input" type='text'>
<button id="changer">change</button>
```

Comment: This works but can be dangerous in case of plugin author will put the `val()` inside `change` event handler.

Comment: that's a valid point, but the only other way I could think to do it is modify the plugin or check that the content has changed at a timeout interval. it's a bit hacky though.

Comment: as @Popnoodles mentioned above there is same solution as yours with one difference: before firing the event it checks if the value was actually changed or not (stackoverflow.com/a/23635867/822711). Works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works because I have never done it. However, according to: [redefining-a-jquery-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267872/redefining-a-jquery-function)
you could redefine jQuery's val function to trigger a change event.

In this way you won't have to touch the plugin and calling `val()` will fire an event every time it is called.
Sample code is included in the link provided.

EDIT: Answers to similar questions state that it is bad practice as sometimes doing so leads to an unpredictable behavior of jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/cqz2u8x8/1/ fiddle for different change events. You might want to try the on('input') event. This seems to trigger every time a real change in value has occured.

```
$("#testinput").on('input', function(e) {
    $("#valuetyped-input").html(e.target.value)
});
```

Comment: Updated your example so you would understand what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/cqz2u8x8/5/. Type something into `#testinput2` and you will see that `#testinput` is updated but events are not triggered